# How to search/replace string for the whole buffer in Emacs without going back to the beginning?

Tags: emacs

It is really inconvenient to first go back to the buffer top and then do the search/query. Well, for search, it is relatively simple that you can just press `C-s` one more time to wrap around, but for query/replace, it's tedious.

Any simple hack to do that without going back to the buffer top for both operations?

Answer (score 6):

Huh, looks like you can't (taken from [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/emacs18/emacs_17.html#SEC77), emphasis mine):

> To replace every instance of 'foo' after point with 'bar', use the command M-x replace-string with the two arguments `foo` and `bar`. **Replacement occurs only after point, so if you want to cover the whole buffer you must go to the beginning first**.

Personally, I split the buffer in two (`C-x 2`), go to the top (`C-Home`) and then run the replace command, switch back to my original pane (`C-x o`) and then kill the second (`C-x 0`). Don't know if there is a trick to make that simpler.

Answer (score 4):

```
(defun my-replace-string ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (call-interactively 'replace-string)))
```

Comment: Works nicely, but screws up query-replace on region/selection (always does on the whole buffer).

Answer (score 1):

I use [iedit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Iedit) for this. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've using below for work with Emacs 24+:

```
;; query replace all from buffer start
(fset 'my-query-replace-all 'query-replace)
(advice-add 'my-query-replace-all
            :around
            #'(lambda(oldfun &rest args)
               "Query replace the whole buffer."
               ;; set start pos
               (unless (nth 3 args)
                 (setf (nth 3 args)
                       (if (region-active-p)
                           (region-beginning)
                         (point-min))))
               (unless (nth 4 args)
                 (setf (nth 4 args)
                       (if (region-active-p)
                           (region-end)
                         (point-max))))
               (apply oldfun args)))
(global-set-key "\C-cr" 'my-query-replace-all)
```

Regard the region replace case, and any START and END args passed.